# Python re with group: to extract char repeating in string and what is char

Tags: python, regex

I found this:

```
>>> re.findall(r'((.)\2*)',s)
[('111', '1'), ('22', '2'), ('1', '1')]
>>> s
'111221'
>>>
```

I'm not able to follow \2*, how does the regex worked: first group gives
me the second group char repeating in s. Its amazing!

\2 meaning the second group, but what is the second group here?!

Note: this is to get number of times a char repeating in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\2` is a backreference to what was captured in capture group 2.
For example, if group 2 captured `b`, `\2+` can only match `b` or `bb`, etc..
Equivalent to `bb+` where 'b' can be any character except newline.

```
 (                 # (1 start)
      ( . )             # (2), Any character
      \2*               # Backreference to capture group 2, 0 to many times
 )                 # (1 end)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example capture group 1 `\1` is `((.)\2*)` and the capture group 2 `\2` is `(.)`

Because you are not using the first capture group, you could use non-capturing group instead: `(?:(.)\1)`